# Snapcraft pushes to wrong snap name

Tags: snap

I built an app and I want to push it via

```
snapcraft push --release=edge violin-player_2.2.0_amd64.snap
```

I get the following error message:

> Received 403: '{"error_list": [{"message": "Cannot upload new revisions > for name=violin", "code": "resource-forbidden"}]}'

Snapcraft tries to push to `violin`, but I want it to push to `violin-player`.

---

How can I tell snapcraft to push to `violin-player`?

Comment: @tatsu Quotes didn't help, neither did a look on all available commands (`snapcraft --help & snapcraft push --help`) :/. The issue is that I have two names registered (`violin` - on another account, not allowed to push there, and `violin-player` - on my account, so I'm allowed to push there). Snapcraft automatically tries to push to `violin` and I couldn't find any way to change the "push destination"

Comment: @tatsu It was a typo... Please take a look at my answer for details. Anyways, thank you for your help!

Comment: okay, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I figured out that the `name` property of my `package.json` file and the snap name I wanted to push to (`violin-player`) didn't match and therefore the .snap file was built incorrectly.

So changing

```
{
  "name": "violin",
  ...
```

to

```
{
  "name": "violin-player",
  ...
```

in my `package.json` file did the trick and pushing was successful.